# Spring Boot OAuth 2 - expiring refresh tokens when password changed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I've created an API using Spring Boot/OAuth. It's currently set so that access_tokens are valid for 30 days, and refresh_tokens are valid for 5 years. It's been requested that OAuth work this way so that a single refresh_token can be used over and over again. What we also need to do is implement some way of expiring refresh tokens when a user changes their password, this is what I'm struggling with as we're not using a token store as we're using JWTs, so there's no need to store the tokens, and even when we were storing that in a database we regularly got 'Invalid refresh token' errors, so removed the token store.

My question is, how to you handle expiring refresh tokens, say, when a user changes their password (as suggested by OAuth).

My client has specifically requested that the returned refresh_token be long-life, but I'm concerned that a long-life refresh token isn't very secure, as if anyone gets hold of that token they can access the users account until that token naturally expires. Personally I'd prefer to set a shorter expiry on refresh_tokens at say 45 days, forcing the client to store a new refresh_token every 45 days at least.

Here's are some of my configuration classes for security to show how I currently have things setup;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountAuthenticationProvider accountAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(accountAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(env.getProperty("jwt.secret"));
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

}



@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "myapi";

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/view/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    //.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revoking token is not supported if JWT is used. If you would like to have this functionality implemented, you should consider using JdbcTokenStore instead.

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() { 
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource()); 
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() { 
    DriverManagerDataSource jdbcdataSource =  new DriverManagerDataSource();
    jdbcdataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    jdbcdataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));//connection String
    jdbcdataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    jdbcdataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")); 
    return dataSource;
}
```

When the user changes password, you should invoke the revokeToken API

```
@Resource(name="tokenServices")
ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tokens/revoke/{tokenId:.*}")
@ResponseBody
public String revokeToken(@PathVariable String tokenId) {
    tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
    return tokenId;
}
```

JDBCTokenStore also exposes a method using which you can invalidate the refresh token

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tokens/revokeRefreshToken/{tokenId:.*}")
@ResponseBody
public String revokeRefreshToken(@PathVariable String tokenId) {
    if (tokenStore instanceof JdbcTokenStore){
        ((JdbcTokenStore) tokenStore).removeRefreshToken(tokenId);
    }
    return tokenId;
}
```